# TinyMCE 4 disable html processing when inserting html in source code

Tags: tinymce-4

It is possible in TinyMCE 4 to paste some custom HTML in source code window, avoiding then TinyMCE modifying it when pressing ok?

Answer (score 0):

To make this possible you would have to allow all elements (since you don't know which elements are in the custom html you're talking about).

```
tinyMCE.init({
    valid_elements : "*[*]"
});
```